# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_delayedShow' of undefined

Tags: javascript, typeerror, progressive-web-apps

i keep getting this error despite changing the values. I am working on converting my blog into a PWA and i got a script for a popup to add my blog to the homescreen but it keeps failing.

> addtohomescreen.min.js:formatted:11 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_delayedShow' of undefined
>       at addtohomescreen.min.js:formatted:11

Here's the code

```
!function(o, s, e) {
    "use strict";
    var t = "com.love2dev.addtohome"
      , i = !1
      , n = localStorage.getItem(t);
    if (!n || !n.added) {
        "onbeforeinstallprompt"in o && (o.addEventListener("beforeinstallprompt", function(o) {
            o.preventDefault(),
            console.log("capturing the native A2HS prompt"),
            d = o,
            a._delayedShow(2)
        }),
        i = !0),
        "onappinstalled"in o && o.addEventListener("appinstalled", function(o) {
            a.doLog("a2hs", "installed"),
            n.added = !0,
            a.updateSession(),
            this.options.onInstall && this.options.onInstall.call(this)
        });
```

I am a beginner currently learning Javascript on the go so go easy on me.

Comment: where is a declared??

Comment: in the site's footer

Comment: Did you find how to solve this issue ?